# разрыв mysql соединения в python скрипте

Tags: python, mysql, telegram-bot, aiogram-3.x

У меня сразу 3 скрипта, которые подключаются к одной и той же базе данных, в начале каждого скрипта  есть подключение:

```
myconn = mysql.connector.connect(host = "localhost", user = "..",passwd = "..",database = "..")
mycursor = myconn.cursor()
```

2 скрипта взаимодействуют с ботом телеграмма(на aiogram 3) и находятся в асинхоронном запуске, т.е. постоянно запущены(через asyncio.run(main()))

1 скрипт - не связан с ботом, но связан с базой данных, которая так же используется в двух других скриптах. Он запущен через бесконечный цикл со слипом в 5 секунд.

Если я запускаю все 3 скрипта, то тот, в котором происходит первое обращение к БД нормально отрабабывает, но остальные начинают выдавать такую ошибку и крашатся:
mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: 2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'localhost:3306', system error: 10053 Программа на вашем хост-компьютере разорвала установленное подключение

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно организовать несколько подключений к БД, чтобы я мог спокойно получать и изменять значения в таблице без ошибок?

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, насколько это правильно, но в итоге мне помогло следующее:

1. я выделил подключение к БД в отдельный файл и подключил его ко всем скриптам
2. начал создавать перед каждым запросом новый курсор и закрывать его в конце выполнения запроса
   После этого ошибка исчезла и всё стало спокойно параллельно работать, база больше не падала

Comment: А вы что-то пишете в базу или только читаете? Так то вы сейчас правильно делаете, лучше соединение и всё прочее на каждую операцию отдельно открывать, да.

Comment: Если сложить все 3 скрипта, то там есть и запись, и обновление, и чтение

Comment: Ну вот я полагаю, что при записи автоматом открывалась транзакция и она лочила таблицу пока курсор не закроется. Поэтому остальные запросы отваливались по таймауту.

Comment: А сам коннекшен можно один оставить? Или лучше тоже на каждый запрос новое соединение открывать и закрывать?

Comment: Это я не помню, надо гуглить. Так на память мне казалось, что коннекшен тоже лучше долго не хранить. Коннекшенов обычно ограниченное число у базы. И они выделяются из пула, то есть выделение коннекшена вроде не такое долгое и не должно особо тормозить.